# Validate Input for time only works if I attached a break point in chrome debugger

Tags: javascript, html

I have some code I want to validate the input, i want to create my own Validator for time rather then using the time type on input as I'm also styling it.

However the current code allows none desired characters [A-Z] to be parsed expect for when I put a break point on the if statement.

Want to add to this to convert the value to always be formatted time (00:00 and 25:93 > 23:59)

```
window.validateTimeInput = function(evt) {
    var e = evt || window.event,
    key = e.keyCode || e.which,
    keyChar = String.fromCharCode(key),
    regexChars = /[0-9]|\:/,
    regexActions = /37|38|39|40|46|27|13|8/; // Left, Up, Right, Down, Delete, Escape, Enter, Backspace

    // BREAK POINT HERE
    if( ( regexChars.test(keyChar) ? false : !regexActions.test(key.toString()) ) && e.target.value.length >= 5 ){
        e.returnValue = false;
        if(e.preventDefault()) e.preventDefault();
        //return false;
    }
};


<input type="text" onkeydown="validateTimeInput();"/>
```

example :
http://jsfiddle.net/labithiotis/YSgUk/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your regex: `/37|38|39|40|46|27|13|8/`. It is too lenient.

It allows the letter "r", keycode 82. Because `/8/` allows the string `"82"`. (Also allows the letters dnpqrstuvwxyDNPQRSTUVWXY.)

Change your regex to this:

```
 /^(37|38|39|40|46|27|13|8)$/
```

Comment: tried doing so and still only works if i place a break point on if statement. created a fiddle to show my point too http://jsfiddle.net/labithiotis/YSgUk/1/

Comment: Hah! you should add `16` to your regex list. The shift key!

Comment: Well, that doesn't seem to do the trick either. An alternative is to assume your users aren't pants-on-head and validate the input later.

Answer (score 0):

Try pulling that line out of the if statement and see if that helps narrow things down.  You could also split your checks up a bit more instead of trying to run them all in one line.

```
$foo = regexChars.test(keyChar) ? false : !regexActions.test(key.toString();
if($foo){
    ...
}
```

Comment: tried that and still the same result only works if I put a break point on the IF statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// $hd = curl_init("http://www.laleo.com/ebooks_android/ebooks_search_json.php");
// curl_setopt($hd,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"query=deporte");
// curl_exec($hd);
// curl_close($hd);
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
var regexp1 = /^[0-2]{1}/;
var regexp2 = /^[0-9]{2}/;
var regexp3 = /^[0-9]{2}\:{1}/;
var regexp4 = /^[0-9]{2}\:{1}[0-5]{1}/;
var regexp5 = /^[0-9]{2}\:{1}[0-9]{2}$/;
$(function(){

    $(":text").keyup(function(evt){
    var curent = $(this);
    if(curent.val().length == 1)
    {
        if(regexp1.test(curent.val()))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            curent.val("");
        }
    }
    else if(curent.val().length == 2)
    {
        if(regexp2.test(curent.val()) && curent.val() < 24)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            curent.val(curent.val().slice(0,1));
        }
    }
    else if(curent.val().length == 3)
    {
        if(regexp3.test(curent.val()))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            curent.val(curent.val().slice(0,2));
        }
    }
    else if(curent.val().length == 4)
    {
        if(regexp4.test(curent.val()))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            curent.val(curent.val().slice(0,3));
        }
    }
    else if(curent.val().length == 5)
    {
        if(regexp5.test(curent.val()))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            curent.val(curent.val().slice(0,4));
        }
    }
    else if(curent.val().length > 5)
    {
        curent.val(curent.val().slice(0,5));
    }
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: dont need a solution for time validation. plus i am going to handle that on changed and not on keydown. I am just stuck on validating keys for some reason.

Comment: already I modified the script, now only allows valid times 23:59